# Assets.car can't be read in Application Loader

Tags: ios, xcode8, application-loader

Hello I am using application loader 3.0 to upload my app to appstore. My Xcode is 8.0 yesterday I uploaded a version to appstore. But today I want to update the version after fixing a bug. But when I try to upload I am getting this error in my Application Loader.

[image]

How can I solve this issue?
Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Using Application loader from the Xcode menu `Xcode -> Open developer tool -> Application Loader` solves the problem. Please make sure you do it from the version of the Xcode that you used to build your app.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I truly overlooked this issue, glad I found your answer in no time.